# opinion poll, t test or paired test or others

Tags: paired-comparisons

Which test should I use to test the difference of monthly opinion poll?

If I want to know whether the poll result of April is significantly different from March, should I use independent t test or paired test?

If I use independent t test, it seems that I am comparing two groups of people instead of change over time, however the samples be totally different between two time points.  So, I am not sure which to use.

Thx!!

Answer (score 1):

A paired test is appropriate when you measured something in the same person/animal/unit before and after an intervention. In your scenario, you have two distinct samples of people, Accordingly, the paired t test makes no sense and would be impossible to compute.

Why are you focussing on April and May? Do you have results for every month for a longer period of time, and are only focussing on April and May because you noticed they are quite different? If so, you are P-hacking, and the results won't mean much, because you are implicitly testing lots of hypotheses, not just one.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? You could also turn it into a comment.

Comment: @gung.I can't think what else to say. I think it answers his question completely. Feel free to expand or delete or...

Comment: It does seem like a short answer basically covers it here, Harvey. I don't think it needs to be deleted (I voted 'looks OK' in the low quality review queue). But it is short & was entered into the LQ queue. It could be a comment. The OP seems concerned about whether an independent t-test can measure "change over time"--certainly we often talk about the dependent t-test as the 1 to use for 'before & after' data. Perhaps you could clarify those issues.